# How can i make array of way points instead many functions for each way point?

Tags: c#, enums, unity-game-engine

The first original code was with 4 way points using `enum` and `switch`,`case`,`state` and each way point have its own function. This was working fine. But now I added a variable name `wayPoints` array of `GameObject`.

Instead, I want to add a new function to each way point to make it in one function. For example, let's say I have 30 cubes and I add them to the `wayPoints` array and now I want the character to walk between the 30 cubes as waypoints. So I added a new `State` and called it `WayPoints`. I also added a new function and called it `WayPoints()`

Now I'm not sure how to continue from here. I still want to use the `enum` idea with the `wayPoints` array but not sure if the case i added is right and how to do it in the `WayPoints()` function.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class MoveObject : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject[] wayPoints;
    public Transform target;
    float moveSpeed = 3f;
    float rotationSpeed = 3f;
    Transform myTransform;
    State state;
    public enum State
    {
        Idle,
        Way1,
        Way2,
        Way3,
        Way4,
        WayPoints
    }
    void Awake()
    {
        myTransform = transform;
    }
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        Debug.Log("Scripts Strart");
        state = State.Idle;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        Debug.Log("Update");
        switch (state)
        {
            case State.Idle:
                Idle();
                break;
            case State.WayPoints:
                WayPoints();
                break;
            case State.Way1:
                waypoint1();
                break;
            case State.Way2:
                waypoint2();
                break;
            case State.Way3:
                waypoint3();
                break;
            case State.Way4:
                waypoint4();
                break;
        }
    }
    public void Idle()
    {
        state = State.Way1;
    }

    void WayPoints()
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < wayPoints.Length; i++)
        {
            wayPoints[i].name = "wayPoint";
            target = GameObject.Find(wayPoints[i].name).transform;
            float distance = Vector3.Distance(myTransform.position, target.transform.position);
            Debug.DrawLine(target.transform.position, myTransform.position, Color.red);
            myTransform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(myTransform.rotation, Quaternion.LookRotation(target.position - myTransform.position), rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime);

            //move towards the player
            myTransform.position += myTransform.forward * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
            if (distance < 2f)
            {

            }
        }
    }

    void waypoint1()
    {
        target = GameObject.Find("W1").transform;
        float distance = Vector3.Distance(myTransform.position, target.transform.position);
        Debug.DrawLine(target.transform.position, myTransform.position, Color.red);
        myTransform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(myTransform.rotation, Quaternion.LookRotation(target.position - myTransform.position), rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime);

        //move towards the player
        myTransform.position += myTransform.forward * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
        if (distance < 2f)
            state = State.Way2;
    }
    void waypoint2()
    {
        target = GameObject.Find("W2").transform;
        float distance = Vector3.Distance(myTransform.position, target.transform.position);
        Debug.DrawLine(target.transform.position, myTransform.position, Color.red);
        myTransform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(myTransform.rotation, Quaternion.LookRotation(target.position - myTransform.position), rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime);

        //move towards the player
        myTransform.position += myTransform.forward * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
        if (distance < 2f)
            state = State.Way3;
    }
    void waypoint3()
    {
        target = GameObject.Find("W3").transform;
        float distance = Vector3.Distance(myTransform.position, target.transform.position);
        Debug.DrawLine(target.transform.position, myTransform.position, Color.red);
        myTransform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(myTransform.rotation, Quaternion.LookRotation(target.position - myTransform.position), rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime);

        //move towards the player
        myTransform.position += myTransform.forward * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
        if (distance < 2f)
            state = State.Way4;
    }
    void waypoint4()
    {
        target = GameObject.Find("W4").transform;
        float distance = Vector3.Distance(myTransform.position, target.transform.position);
        Debug.DrawLine(target.transform.position, myTransform.position, Color.red);
        myTransform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(myTransform.rotation, Quaternion.LookRotation(target.position - myTransform.position), rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime);

        //move towards the player
        myTransform.position += myTransform.forward * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
        if (distance < 2f)
            state = State.Way1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has a well implented waypoints system you might want to take a look at: https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/scripting/using-interfaces-make-state-machine-ai

You should make a simple public GameObject[] waypoints and drag and drop your desired waypoints in there and use an index to loop thorugh them. This can replace the first line of code so you can use them same method.